# Where to find HibernateSession while mocking using mockito + spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, mockito, hibernate-session

I am trying to mock the HibernateSession and SessionFactory

I am unable to resolve the below in spring mvc

`@Mock private HibernateSession hibernateSession;`

I have added the below dependencies

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>`
```

Both do not seem to have the HibernateSession class.

Comment: What is the final goal you want to achieve/test?

Comment: What class are you precisely looking for? Hibernate has `org.hibernate.Session`, not `HibernateSession`

Comment: @Nik I am looking to mock the HibernateTemplate or a HibernateSession

Comment: @Lesiak True. I was looking for mocking a hibernate session.

Comment: @shaen Is your problem solved now?

Comment: @Lesiak I haven't yet found a solution. looking for the same.

Comment: @shaen Can you post the precise error message you are getting and the problematic file (I understand that the problem presists after changing `HibernateSession` to ` Session`)